# What exactly is a git server?

Tags: git

I understand that a git server hosts the master copy of a git repository. But what technically constitutes one? If I am in Eclipse, for example, and configure a remote in my repository is there anything special that that remote must be? Could the remote just be a folder inside a mapped network drive on a windows server? I'm wondering because I see a range of options to connect with the remote, including local file.

I suppose what my question boils down to, is are there special git protocol stuff that a git server must handle, or is it really just a means of serving the files that comprise the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the remote just be a folder inside a mapped network drive on a
>   windows server? I'm wondering because I see a range of options to
>   connect with the remote, including local file.

Yes, it can just be as simple as a local folder. Of course that is if you don't need any authentication or authorization.

> I suppose what my question boils down to, is are there special git
>   protocol stuff that a git server must handle, or is it really just a
>   means of serving the files that comprise the repository?

There is two protocols one over HTTP and another over SSH. I believe the HTTP protocol is read only for all and has no authorization, but I don't remember.

The SSH protocol though is an easy way to set up a git server on any computer you have SSH access to. Underneath, each time you call `git push` or `git pull` your installed `git` will SSH to the server and run either `git receive pack` or `git upload pack` respectively and proceed with a protocol that will determine the smallest `PACK` file that you can either send or receive to meet your needs.

You can read all the dirty details about the git protocol [here](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-protocol.txt) or [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Transfer-Protocols) is a simpler explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You can communicate with a remote Git repo over a number of protocols: ssh, rsync, local files, ftp, and, yes, a special Git protocol, to name a few (a broader list is available [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls) and [here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html)). Git ships with a tool, [`git-daemon`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-daemon.html) for handling its own git protocol, if you choose to set a server up in such a way.